# Material-UI Button and ButtonGroup do not align on the baseline

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Can someone explain why Button and ButtonGroup do not align on the baseline in the example below? Is there a property I can change on the ButtonGroup element to make them align?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Fonts to support Material Design -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
    <!-- Icons to support Material Design -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
const {
  Grid,
  Button,
  ButtonGroup
} = MaterialUI;

function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container alignItems="baseline">
      <Grid item>
        <Button variant="outlined">Cancel</Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <ButtonGroup>
          <Button variant="outlined">Submit</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.querySelector('#root'),
);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use the `last baseline` option of the `align-items` CSS property. Unfortunately it is not supported by the MUI system, so you will need to use classes or inline style for that: `<Grid container style={{alignItems: 'last baseline'}}>`.

Comment: Well, this works for the example I posted here (just as alignItems="center" does, for example). But it breaks baseline alignment for other elements in the Grid in my real-world scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954501/material-ui-grid-baseline-alignment-for-button-buttongroup-and-typography

And, it does not explain where this misalignment is coming from.

Comment: I saw your other question. I think this is not related to material-ui, but a pure CSS question, and if you will remove all the noise of the material/react things, and just open a pure html-css question with the output of the react/material code you will get a quick answer on "why is this happening" :-)

Comment: If I tried to implement this layout in a pure HTML/CSS, I'm sure I would not have this problem :) The root cause is definitely somewhere in Material UI CSS. And I'm asking these questions because I want to learn how to use Material UI properly, as the authors intended.

Comment: @Dekel the funny thing is that I just found a way to align all elements in that other question! 

That includes a pretty dumb solution to this one as well: just wrap the first <Button> in a dummy <ButtonGroup>... Does not explain the source of misalignment though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align them `baseline`, you can override the `display` css with `block` instead of `inline-flex`. You can do this by using the `component` props on `<ButtonGroup>`.

```
<ButtonGroup component={Box} display="block !important">
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually works!

But I'm struggling to understand it. Why is it necessary? The ButtonGroup's <div> element had `display:inline-flex` just as the "Cancel" <button> element, so what was causing the misalignment?

Comment: You are welcome :) Pretty sure the `inline-flex` property is used for grouping multiple buttons to allow them to flex while displaying inline. If you are not using multiple Buttons I don't see the reason to use `<ButtonGroup>` if that make sense.

Comment: Right, but I actually do use multiple buttons inside a ButtonGroup in a real-world situation. The problem is that if I have a standalone Button and a ButtonGroup in the same Grid row, they don't align (unless I apply your fix or wrap standalone Button in a dummy ButtonGroup).